# Remove a certificate from the Windows "Network Service" certificate store

Tags: windows, certificate

I have a service, running with the "Network Service" permissions that installed a certificate into the "personal certificate store" for the "Network Service".

For reasons that are beyond the scope of this question, I need to remove that certificate, but using the MMC's "Certificates" snap-in I failed to find that certificate. I tried opening the certificate store for "Service"->"Local machine"->"Service name", but there's nothing there while the service definitely reports that it sees the certificate.

Any idea how do I access that personal certificate store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registry editor.

HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My

S-1-5-20 is the Network Service account. "My" represents the Personal store.

Delete the entries from there.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185059

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to mess with Registry, see: [How do you install a certificate in a PFX file in to the personal container of the NT-AUTHORITY\NetworkService?](https://serverfault.com/questions/261195/how-do-you-install-a-certificate-in-a-pfx-file-in-to-the-personal-container-of-th)
It is talking about installation, but nothing prevents you from deleting a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Using psexec utility from Microsoft / sysinternals did the trick for me.

1. Download psexec. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools
2. Open up a new console using psexec that will run as NETWORK SERVICE:

   .\PsExec64.exe -i -u "nt authority\network service" powershell
3. Run mmc
4. Add snapin for Certificate and use certificates from "My User Account"
5. Do whatever you want with the personal certificates for this account

All personal certificates should be visible for NETWORK SERVICE now.

This was at least needed for me to run the tool mage.exe that had a hard time doing code signing under the NETWORK SERVICE account since it only uses personal certificates.